# Issue on Reseting (Deselecting) Bootstrap Radio Buttons

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/2nZww/) and let me know why I am not able to Deselect all Radio Buttons by using following code:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="radioopt">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Option 1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Option 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Option 3
  </label>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="deselect">Reset</button>

<script>
  $("#deselect").on("click",function(){
    $(".btn-group button").removeClass("active");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: please take a look this link http://jsfiddle.net/2nZww/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work. Your selector is wrong and also you aren't closing your `on` method.

```
$("#deselect").on("click",function(){
  $(".btn-group .btn").removeClass("active");
});
```

Also if you really want to know the active isn't being applied to the input radio it's being applied to the parent so if you *really* want to select just radios then you would have to select the radios and then the parent like so:

```
$("#deselect").on("click",function(){
 $('input:radio').parent().removeClass("active");
});
```

**EDIT**

Here is an example that alerts the value

http://jsfiddle.net/Wcq2F/

Updated version:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wcq2F/45/

Comment: Thanks Thunda , just one small question can you also please let me know how to get the VALUE of the selected radio? Do we have to add value attribute too?

Comment: I can't get the radio group unset by clicking the Reset-Button in your fiddle, Thunda. What am I doing wrong :o)

Comment: Hey @peter I made an edit with an updated fiddle. Please take a look at that...it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--input radio button group for  boot strap-->
    <label id="labelsecenek" class="btn btn-primary secenek secenekrb" style="color: #fff; background-color:#232323;  border-color:#232323;">
                                                <input type="radio" name="renksecenek" id="secenek1" value="1" autocomplete="off">Radio Button 1
                                            </label>

    <script>
/*This script do: when clicked checked a radiobutton, this radiobutton will be unchecked. note: if click another radio button already this button will be unchecked*/
                                        var pasifyap = false;
                                        var click = null;
                                        var thisobj = null;
                                        $(function () {
                                            $(".secenekrb").mousedown(function (e) {
                                                if ($(this).find("[type='radio']").prop("checked") == true) {
                                                    pasifyap = true;
                                                    thisobj =this;
                                                }
                                            });
                                            $(".secenekrb").mouseup(function (e) {
                                                setTimeout(function(){
                                                    if (pasifyap) {
                                                        $(thisobj).find("[type='radio']").prop("checked", false);
                                                        $(thisobj).removeClass("active");
                                                        pasifyap = false;
                                                    }
                                                },100)
                                            });
                                        });
                                    </script>
```

Comment: Please include some language to what the code is doing, perhaps with comments? Thanks!